# Why am I unable to #ifdef stdafx.h?

Tags: conditional-compilation, stdafx.h

I am trying to include 2 platform-specific **stdafx.h** files in my .cpp file, but the compiler is unhappy when I try to #ifdef it.

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include "stdafx.h"
#elif _MAC
#include "MAC/stdafx.h"
#endif
```

You may wonder why I am using stdafx.h in the Mac code, but that is not important at the moment :).

When I try to compile the code on Windows, I receive: **Fatal Error C1018**. I tried enclosing other header files with #ifdef in the same file, and the compiler was happy.  Therefore, it looks like Windows doesn't like stdafx.h to be #ifdef-ed, or that Windows only allows **#include stdafx.h**
to be the first line in the file.

So my question is, why?

Kat

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When the compiler includes a pre-compiled header, it basically "forgets" anything that came before the header. Thus your #elif isn't matched to a #if anymore.

Answer (score 6):

This is because you have Precompiled Headers turned on - turn it off and you should be fine.