# Cin and Cout not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, cin

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Variables in which student info is stored
    string name = "";

    //asks user for their name
    cout << "/nHello, my name is Hal, what is your name? ";

    cin >> name;

    cout << "/nWelcome to C++ ";
    cout << name;
    cout << ", let the adventure begin!";

    return 0;
}
```

Really basic code that I can't seem to get to work. Everywhere I have cin or cout the compiler says they're an undeclared identifier. I've looked at all of the answers on here and other forums and it none of the solutions seem to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you compiling?

Comment: Visual studio 2015

Comment: Are you sure you're using c++? The program compiles fine with g++ on this end. sans `include stdafx.h` of course.

Comment: Im using a visual c++ win32 console application from visual studio

Comment: You should probably add a tag for visual studio, this looks like a Visual Studio problem. You might try uninstalling VS and re-installing it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726155/whats-the-use-for-stdafx-h-in-visual-studio 

"Simply list all your big huge headers for your APIs in your stdafx.h file, in the appropriate order, and then start each of your CPP files at the very top with an #include "stdafx.h", before any meaningful content (just about the only thing allowed before is comments)."

Comment: Try to define cout and cin as its the main problem :

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

Comment: When i had cout and sin defined directly and didnt have the using namespace std it threw even more errors

Comment: What happens when you move the `#include stdafx.h` to the top of the file?

Comment: This is basically the same problem as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435804/why-am-i-unable-to-ifdef-stdafx-h , even though the code before stdafx.h is different. The accepted answer applies though.

Comment: Sebastian fixed it. Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope you have the "stdafx.h" file that you are trying to include in the right path. The code works fine without the file being included.

Comment: how would I check this?

Comment: Just remove the line that includes "stdafx.h". Use this online c++ compiler to check [C++ compiler](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php)